Reloading wrapped website in Swift webView when receiving URL from OneSignal push notification
I've found some information about how to possibly do this for Android, but looking for help with Swift. When a user taps on a push notification (from OneSignal), I want to load the URL passed from the push notification into the webView. Right now, the app correctly launches with the default URL, but it does not update the view when the notification is tapped.
In my current logs, I can see that the URL is being passed correctly, but I keep getting an error that the Webview is not ready so the received URL can't be processed.
The passed URL would be in the format of https://example.com/chat/123, passed as part of the "data" call from OneSignal.
Thank you in advance for any guidance.
Current Swift code:
import SwiftUI
import OneSignalFramework
import UserNotifications
import WebKit


@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    var viewController: ViewController?
    var notificationQueue: [String] = []

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        viewController = ViewController()

        if let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first {
            window.rootViewController = viewController
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }

        OneSignal.Debug.setLogLevel(.LL_VERBOSE)
        OneSignal.initialize("xxx", withLaunchOptions: launchOptions)

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { granted, error in
            if granted {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                }
            }
        }

        if let notification = launchOptions?[.remoteNotification] as? [String: AnyObject] {
            handleNotification(userInfo: notification)
        }

        return true
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        globalDeviceTokenString = deviceToken.map { String(format: "%02X", $0) }.joined()
        print("Device token received: \(globalDeviceTokenString!)")
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("Failed to register for remote notifications: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        print("Received Remote Notification: \(userInfo)")
        handleNotification(userInfo: userInfo)
        completionHandler(.newData)
    }

    private func handleNotification(userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
        guard let data = userInfo["data"] as? [String: Any], let targetUrl = data["targetUrl"] as? String else {
            print("Notification did not contain a valid targetUrl.")
            return
        }

        print("Notification received with targetUrl: \(targetUrl)")

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let viewController = self.viewController, viewController.isWebViewReady {
                viewController.loadUrlIfNeeded(URL(string: targetUrl))
            } else {
                print("WebView not ready, queuing URL: \(targetUrl)")
                if !self.notificationQueue.contains(targetUrl) {
                    self.notificationQueue.append(targetUrl)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func processNotificationQueue() {
        guard let viewController = viewController, viewController.isWebViewReady else {
            print("WebView not ready when processing queue.")
            return
        }

        while !notificationQueue.isEmpty {
            if let url = notificationQueue.first {
                print("Processing queued URL: \(url)")
                viewController.loadUrlIfNeeded(URL(string: url))
                notificationQueue.removeFirst()
            }
        }
    }
}

extension Notification.Name {
    static let webViewDidFinishLoading = Notification.Name("webViewDidFinishLoading")
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKScriptMessageHandler, WKNavigationDelegate, WKUIDelegate {
    var webView: WKWebView!
    var isWebViewReady: Bool = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupWebView()
    }

    private func setupWebView() {
        let contentController = WKUserContentController()
        contentController.add(self, name: "notificationPromptHandler")
        contentController.add(self, name: "nativeSignal")

        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        config.userContentController = contentController

        webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.bounds, configuration: config)
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webView.uiDelegate = self

        self.view.addSubview(webView)

        loadInitialWebContent()
    }

    private func loadInitialWebContent() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://example.com/") else { return }
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    }

    func loadUrlIfNeeded(_ url: URL?) {
        guard let url = url else { return }

        if webView.url != url {
            print("Loading URL: \(url)")
            webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        } else {
            print("URL already loaded, skipping: \(url)")
        }
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        if !isWebViewReady {
            isWebViewReady = true
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .webViewDidFinishLoading, object: nil)
            print("WebView finished loading and is now ready.")
            (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.processNotificationQueue()
        }
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
        print("WebView failed to load with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        if message.name == "notificationPromptHandler" {
            promptForPushNotifications()
        } else if message.name == "nativeSignal" {
            executeJavaScriptFunction(named: "native", with: "yes")
        }
    }

    private func promptForPushNotifications() {
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.getNotificationSettings { settings in
            switch settings.authorizationStatus {
            case .authorized:
                print("Push notifications are already authorized.")
                self.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            case .denied:
                print("Push notifications are denied.")
                self.openSettings()
            case .notDetermined:
                self.requestPushNotificationPermission()
            case .provisional, .ephemeral:
                print("Push notifications are provisionally authorized.")
                self.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            @unknown default:
                self.requestPushNotificationPermission()
            }
        }
    }

    private func requestPushNotificationPermission() {
        OneSignal.Notifications.requestPermission({ accepted in
            if accepted {
                print("Push notification permission granted.")
                self.executeJavaScriptFunction(named: "device", with: "\(globalDeviceTokenString ?? "unknown_device_token")")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                }
            } else {
                print("User did not accept push notification permission requests.")
            }
        }, fallbackToSettings: true)
    }

    private func registerForRemoteNotifications() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }
    }

    private func openSettings() {
        if let url = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        }
    }

    private func executeJavaScriptFunction(named functionName: String, with argument: String) {
        let jsCode = "\(functionName)('\(argument)');"
        print("Executing JavaScript function: \(functionName) with argument: \(argument)")
        webView.evaluateJavaScript(jsCode) { (result, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error executing JavaScript: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                print("JavaScript executed successfully.")
            }
        }
    }
}

